# Keep header, image and first <li> of <ol> together

Tags: css, page-break

I am writing a user manual for my work, which is a text that should be printable. It's an instruction manual where following sequence appears often: header + image (centered, on separate line) + numbered list (with instruction steps)

I would like the header, the image below and the first item of the numbered list to always stay together, i.e. never page break, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

I've tried to define h1, img {page-break-after:avoid;} in combination with img, ol {page-break-before:avoid;} in my css, but those don't catch on.

I tried enclosing the trio in a table with table{page-break-inside:avoid;}, but the problem is that that doesn't respect my ordered list if I close the table after the first item. **I don't want to enclose the entire ordered list in a table**, because the instructions (with their corresponding images) can span several pages anyway.

I tried div instead of table, but the numbering isn't respected either, and then I tried enclosing the trio with p and afterwards span. These do allow the ordered list to continue properly after the first list item, but they again don't respect the {page-break-inside:avoid}.

Any elegant solution?

Comment: Enclose the whole thing in a div and apply `page-break-inside:avoid` to the div. Or try another browser (page-break handling still varies a lot between browsers; you haven't said which ones you tested. But don't use tables.)

Comment: I tried divs, but I don't want to enclose the entire ol in a div because some ols span several pages while others less than half a page: I would get too many page breaks and IMO it doesn't look nice. I tried /div after the first /li, but then the next li resets to either 1 or turns into a bullet. I would obviously like to avoid setting <ol start=__>. I have only tried Chrome as a browser but I visited some forums where people complain about all major browsers. I've heard that Konqueror applies page-break[before/after] correctly to begin with, but our office pc's are 100% Windows environment.

Comment: @MrLister, why do you advise against tables?

Comment: Because tables are much more volatile than divs when it comes to page-break properties. Give a table row such a property and you'll know you'll be creating browser incompatibilities. Believe me, I know. Now about the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put the image inside the first list item.
Then a bit of positioning to get the layout right, and `page-break-inside:avoid` on the list item and you're done.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <figcaption>This is the picture</figcaption>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
    </figure>
    This is point one.
  </li>
  <li>
    This is point two.
  </li>
  etc.
```

```css
li {font-size:16px; line-height:20px; page-break-inside:avoid}
li:first-child {padding-top:120px; position:relative}
li:first-child figure {position:absolute; top:0; margin:0 0 0 -40px;}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/EXKZ8/2/).

[image]